# h.264 video codec in konqueror

Tags: linux, fedora, video-encoding, konqueror

Visiting the page

```
https://www.youtube.com/html5
```

from within  `konqueror` I saw that the `H.264 video codec` is not supported.

My question is: Is it possible to enable it for `konqueror` in any way?

I'm running `Linux Fedora 27` and many other browsers on my PC do support rendering of `h.264` videos without any problem: for instance `firefox`, `opera`, `chromium`, `epiphany` ... all of them work fine with respect to `h.264` contents. So I guess that it is not a lack of something at system level.

Answers welcome.

Comment: Silly question, but I have to ask: do you have `ffmpeg` libs installed?

Comment: Why "silly"? Silly questions do not exist; may be there exist silly answers...

Comment: Anyway yes: I have installed  ffmpeg-libs  AND gstreamer-ffmpeg